# how to assign values from 1 dataframe to a new column in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes...

the first dataframe, `mapoc_temp` looks like this

```
   month year       ave
1   Jan 2016    6.529222
2   Jan 2017    5.720514
3   Jan 2018    5.786351
4   Feb 2016    6.435445
5   Feb 2017    5.817282
6   Feb 2018    5.790529
7   Mar 2016    6.505259
8   Mar 2017    5.852279
9   Mar 2018    5.683220
10  Apr 2016    6.525603
11  Apr 2017    5.769720
12  Apr 2018    5.762235
13  May 2016    6.425552
14  May 2017    5.855167
15  May 2018    5.778975
16  June    2016    6.488962
17  June    2017    5.871033
18  June    2018    5.720514

mapoc_temp = structure(list(month = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Jan", 
"Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", 
"Nov", "Dec"), class = "factor"), year = c(2016, 2017, 2018, 
2016, 2017, 2018), ave = c(6.52922242976571, 5.72051368352674, 
5.78635119450037, 6.43544457584707, 5.81728212255571, 5.79052889374
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(month = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Jan", 
"Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", 
"Nov", "Dec"), class = "factor"), .rows = list(1:3, 4:6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

and my second dataframe, `individual_dets`, looks like this

```
individual_dets = structure(list(location = c("ARB-04", "BIRCHY HEAD", "Boca1", 
"BON-AR-S2", "BON-AR-S2", "BON-W-S5"), month = structure(c(12L, 
10L, 10L, 8L, 11L, 2L), .Label = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", 
"May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), detection_count = c(3L, 
256L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L), num_unique_tags = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), total_res_time_in_seconds = c(0, 1182040, 0, 2732221, 0, 
0), latitude = c(24.94808, 44.5713, 26.32559, -49.27732, -49.27732, 
-49.27985), longitude = c(-80.45412, -64.03512, -80.07108, 69.48038, 
69.48038, 69.47853), zone = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), ave_temp = c(5.740993, 
5.855167, 5.855167, 5.852279, 5.871033, 5.790529)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    month = structure(c(2L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("Jan", 
    "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", 
    "Nov", "Dec"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), .rows = list(
        6L, 4L, 2:3, 5L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

I'd like to take the values from column `ave` in the `mapoc_dets` dataframe and make sure those values are assigned to the corresponding month and year in `individual_dets`

I've tried using the following code, but I was hoping someone might know how to shorten this code

```
individual_dets = individual_dets %>% 
  group_by(month) %>%
  mutate(ave_temp = 
           if_else(month == "Jan" && year == 2016 , 6.529222,
            if_else (month == "Feb" && year == 2016, 6.435445,
            if_else(month == "Mar" && year == 2016, 6.505259,
            if_else(month == "Apr" && year == 2016, 6.525603,
             if_else (month == "May" && year == 2016, 6.425552,
             if_else (month == "Jun" && year == 2016, 6.488962,
             if_else (month == "Jul" && year == 2016, 6.490498,
             if_else (month == "Aug" && year == 2016, 6.417815,
             if_else (month == "Sep" && year == 2016, 6.492893,
             if_else (month == "Oct" && year == 2016, 6.502256,
             if_else (month == "Nov" && year == 2016, 6.427294,
             if_else (month == "Dec" && year == 2016, 6.508574,

            if_else(month == "Jan" && year == 2017 , 5.720514,
            if_else (month == "Feb" && year == 2017, 5.817282,
            if_else(month == "Mar" && year == 2017, 5.852279,
            if_else(month == "Apr" && year == 2017, 5.769720,
            if_else (month == "May" && year == 2017, 5.855167,
            if_else (month == "Jun" && year == 2017, 5.871033,
            if_else (month == "Jul" && year == 2017, 5.740993,
            if_else (month == "Aug" && year == 2017, 5.786351,
            if_else (month == "Sep" && year == 2017, 5.790529,
            if_else (month == "Oct" && year == 2017, 5.683220,
            if_else (month == "Nov" && year == 2017, 5.762235,
            if_else (month == "Dec" && year == 2017, 5.778975, 

             if_else(month == "Jan" && year == 2018 , 5.786351,
             if_else (month == "Feb" && year == 2018, 5.790529,
             if_else(month == "Mar" && year == 2018, 5.683220,
             if_else(month == "Apr" && year == 2018, 5.762235,
             if_else (month == "May" && year == 2018, 5.778975,
             if_else (month == "Jun" && year == 2018, 5.720514,
             if_else (month == "Jul" && year == 2018, 5.817282,
             if_else (month == "Aug" && year == 2018, 5.852279,
             if_else (month == "Sep" && year == 2018, 5.769720,
             if_else (month == "Oct" && year == 2018, 5.855167,
             if_else (month == "Nov" && year == 2018, 5.871033,
             if_else (month == "Dec" && year == 2018, 5.740993, 0
              ))))))))))))
            )))))))))))))
             ))))))))))))
```

Comment: That I would create a keyval data and do a join, i.e `crossing(month = month.abb, year = 2016:2018) %>% mutate(value = ..) %>% right_join(originaldata)`

Comment: `ave_temp` column which is present in `individual_dets` doesn't change at all after running the code which you have. How do you want to get the `ave` values from `mapoc_temp`? By `month` or `year` or both?

Comment: both month and year

Answer (score 0):

After `ungroup`ing the datasets and converting the columns to join to be on the same `class` we can use a `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- individual_dets %>% 
         ungroup %>%
         mutate(month = as.character(month)) %>%
         left_join(mapoc_temp %>%
           ungroup %>%
           mutate(month = as.character(month)), by = c("year", "month") )
```

Comment: that gives me the column, but it's full of na's

Comment: @KristenCyr It is based on the example where the combinations for 'year', 'month' are not present in one of the dataset.